# Importing multiple CSV files into one RData FILE

Tags: r, csv

I have multiple CSV files I would like to import into R; then save those as an `initState.Rdata` file; is that possible?

Currently I'm importing them as follows

```
Users <- read.csv('/Users/AndyD/Desktop/Data/DeakinUsersData.csv')
PagePaths <- read.csv('/Users/AndyD/Desktop/Data/DeakinPageData.csv')
Goals <- read.csv('/Users/AndyD/Desktop/Data/Deakin_Goals.csv')
```

Is it possible to import those and include them all in a `initState.Rdata`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `save()` function for this:

```
save(Users, PagePaths, Goals, file = "initState.RData")
```

If you don't mind saving everything in the current session, you can also use `save.image()`:

```
save.image(file = "initState.RData")
```

Comment: Cheers Tim all bang on !

Comment: @AndyDonaldson Bang on to you to!

Comment: hmmmm Error in readRDS("initState.Rdata") : unknown input format when i run my shiny app code

Comment: CVtune <- readRDS('initState.Rdata') ..returns this error any ideas?

Comment: Any reason why you are not using `load`?  See here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/load.html

Comment: I tried that and it rid me of that message ..when you combine say 3 CSV flies into an RData file do the files Need to be of the same dimensions ? Rows columns etc

Comment: As my app still crashes

Comment: @AndyDonaldson You need to open a new question.  Stack Overflow is not an ongoing blog with endless follow up questions.  You have an answer to your initial question.